# How to compare the performance of Theano and Tensorflow? Highest lvl functions or the fastest low lvl implementations?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, lstm

Firstly, I'm assuming that a low level conscious implementation would lead to the most efficient implementation (in terms of time and memory consumption).

I just want to measure their performances on some **LSTM** architectures in different problems for a work I'm doing at the moment. Currently, my code is structured like this

- **Tensorflow**:
  For forward propagation I'm using **tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()** , which seems pretty high level to me. I then define the output bias and weights through **tf.Variable()**, calculate logits with **tf.matmul()** and losses with **tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()** 
  For training I use **tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize()**, which looks extremely high level.
- **Theano**:
  My Theano implementation looks more low level. I took it from Denny Britz implementation as he described on his site (http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-network-tutorial-part-4-implementing-a-grulstm-rnn-with-python-and-theano/) But I did some minor alterations. The foward propagation is made  almost manually, declaring almost all operations inside LSTM with theano functions such as **th.nnet.hard_sigmoid()**, **t.tanh()**, **t.ones_like()**, **t.softmax()**, and **numpy** functions for matrix multiplications. The function runs through a loop using **theano.scan()** function. Backpropagation is also made almost manually, using **th.grad()** for gradient calculus and **th.function()** with updates for updating the waits.

So what do you think? Is that a fair comparison? Or should I seek a more equal amount of encapsulation between the 2 implementations? If you wish, I can include more details about my code, or even a sketch of it. The kind of problems deal with natural language processing and generation. Perhaps I will include a feel more. I will be using a LSTM with 2 levels.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this out for benchmarks for RNN performance of Theano, Tensorflow and Torch deep learning frameworks:

https://github.com/glample/rnn-benchmarks

I might be a bit old given this is an area that develops very fast, but you might use it as a starting point for an updated benchmark.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.